# HTTP Request to Stop or Terminate MJPEG streaming

Tags: c++, http, poco, mjpeg

I have written the MJPEG streaming server on HTTP. My HTTP server receives the request and sends the MJPEG. So far it is working fine. I am using C++ and POCO library.

The problem that I don't know when to stop the streaming. On stopping the browsing from browser (firefox) it sends same request as when requesting the stream. I used fiddler and following is the HTTP request while requesting and stopping the browser.

Requesting the MJPEG from browser (firefox):

```
GET http://mymjpegserver.com?vms=dvtel&deviceid=1&rgb=true&server=10.8.10.80&userid=admin&password= HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.1.39.7:8081
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

Stopping the streaming from browser (firefox) by clicking on cross "x" button

```
GET http://mymjpegserver.com?vms=dvtel&deviceid=1&rgb=true&server=10.8.10.80&userid=admin&password= HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.1.39.7:8081
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

And then after few moments when ever I switch browser tabs or window it sends following request

```
GET http://mymjpegserver.com?vms=dvtel&deviceid=1&rgb=true&server=10.8.10.80&userid=admin&password= HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.1.39.7:8081
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0
Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

That is only Accept value is changed to "image/png...". But, I can not use this Accept value to differentiate the termination, since this request is only sent when the Tab/Window is switched.

And on closing the Tab, nothing sent to the Http Server.

My question is, how on Web Server I can check the request to stop the streaming?

Comment: I'm fairly sure there is no such thing. The web-browser (or plugin) will simply stop requesting more material, and the stream will disappear.

Comment: "stop requesting", does it mean the client (browser/plugin) closes the socket ?

Comment: Probably, but clearly the transmission of a movie is not just one single "give me the video", there will be packets going in both directions, so the client will request "more" of the video. Those requests stop coming when the client don't need to view more video.